# CSS Drop Down Menu - Child li items close on click - jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

Looking for help on a simple jQuery to close ul ul li items on click. here is my fiddler..

http://jsfiddle.net/triplett/ux3vx1Lz/

```
<div id='flyout_menu'>
<ul>
   <li onClick=”return true”><a href='#'><span>title</span></a>
      <ul>
               <li><a href='#'><span> sub title </span></a></li>

         <li><a href='#'><span> sub title </span></a></li>

<li><a href='#'><span>sub title</span></a></li>


   </ul></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input and sorry for not being clear in my request. your solution worked. 

one more thing if I want the parent Ul to remain active when click?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understand well what you want, but here is what i understood.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/don/ux3vx1Lz/5/

When you click on ul ul li, the ul ul is closed, is that?

---

Sample jQuery:

```
$('ul ul li').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().hide();
});

$('ul li').on('mouseover', function() {
    $(this).find('ul').show();
});
```

Comment: Updated the code (and demo) and added support to show again when hover the menu.

Answer (score 1):

JS:

```
$('ul ul li a').on('click', function () {
  $(this).closest("ul").addClass("hidden");
});
$('ul li').on('mouseover', function () {
  $(this).find('ul').removeClass("hidden");
});
```

CSS:

```
.hidden{
  display:none;
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ux3vx1Lz/6/)

Answer (score 0):

since your menu is a css only menu, we'll keep it that way. use the :active selector. 
just change the following in your fiddle:

```
#flyout_menu ul ul,
#flyout_menu ul:active{ //<-- this one is the new row, to hide the clicked ul
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 80%;
    z-index: 584598;
}
```

this has some downsides though - it also triggers, if you click the main title, resulting in a flickering of the main title...

i'd suggest to completely rebuild the show and hide functionality with js and use css for styling/position purposes only.
i'd also suggest, that you use class names and id's for every level of your menu, since you could address the single elements easier that way. it's always better to look for .subItem than for #menu ul ul li!